# how can I shutdown my system from the console with a command?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, windows-2000, process-hacker

how can I shutdown my system from the console with a command?
I am new to programming console :/

[image: screenshot]

I already tried:

```
windows.exit
windows.norun
windows shauwtdownnow
```

Comment: The command prompt isn't really "programming" per-say. With normal use it's just various commands that you use to do certain things, which can be controlled by using "switches". You can type `help` in the command prompt to get a generic list of commands, then after that usually typing `commandhere /?` or `commandhere --help` will display help for the command you put where commandhere is. When you start using batch files and start using statements, that's when it starts becoming "programming".

Comment: how is windows 95 relevant here? this should be found easily with a simple google search

Comment: what do you mean? i no say win 95, but 2000, the year of my gebirth <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shutdown -s` to shut the pc down. You can also use `shutdown -r` to reboot or `shutdown -h` to hibernate.

Comment: The full range of the `shutdown` command options can be shown by typing `shutdown /?`. Also, see [this link](https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html).